# Помогите с быстрой сортировкой

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, qsort, векторы

Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x7754641B (ntdll.dll) в Быстрая сортировка.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (параметры: 0x00000001, 0x00E02FFC)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

vector <int> qsor(vector <int> arr) {
    vector<int> left;
    vector<int> right;
    int mid = arr[float((0 + arr.size()) / 2)];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] <= mid)
            left.push_back(arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] > mid)
            right.push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    if (left.size() != 0)
        left = qsor(left);
    if (right.size() != 0)
        right = qsor(right);

    return(arr);
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    vector <int> ttemp1 = { 1, 8, 5, 7, 3, 2, 6 };
    vector <int> ttemp2;
    ttemp2 = qsor(ttemp1);
    for (int i = 0; i < ttemp2.size(); i++)
        cout << ttemp2[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Странная у вас сортировка, результатом работы вашей функции является входной аргумент `arr` который никак не меняется. Плюс к этому у вас постоянная рекурсия, т.к после цикла либо `left` либо `right` будет содержать хотя бы один элемент.

Comment: Как уже сказал @Rikitikitavi, ошибка StackOverflow (всегда ждал, когда на SO напишут ошибку про SO) вызвана бесконечной рекурсией.

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Comment: Для mid лучше выбирать случайный элемент)

Answer (score 1):

При реализации быстрой сортировки необходимо следить, чтобы длины подмассивов после разбиения были строго меньше чем длина разбиваемого массива.

Передадим массив `arr == {1, 3, 2}` в вашу сортировку. В качестве опорного значения `mid` будет выбрано число `3`. В подмассив `left` будут помещены все значения меньше либо равные опорному значению. Т.е. `left == {1, 3, 2}`. В подмассив `right` будут помещены все элементы большие, чем опорный элемент. Так как в массиве `arr == {1, 3, 2}` таких элементов нет, то массив `right` будет пустым.

Затем функция `qsor` вызывает себя, передавая в качестве аргумента массив `left = {1, 3, 2}`. Всё повторяется снова. Функция будет вызывать рекурсивно себя до тех пор, пока не исчерпает стек.

Как вариант можно разбивать исходный массив не на два подмассива, а на три: элементы меньшие опорного, элементы большие опорного и элементы равные опорному. Затем сортировать только меньшие и большие элементы.

[Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1836bfa4320027ef):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

std::vector<int> qsor(std::vector<int> arr)
{
    if (arr.size() < 2)
        return arr;

    std::vector<int> left;
    std::vector<int> right;
    std::vector<int> middle;
    int mid = arr[arr.size() / 2];
    
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < mid)
            left.push_back(arr[i]);
        else if (arr[i] > mid)
            right.push_back(arr[i]);
        else
            middle.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    
    left = qsor(left);
    right = qsor(right);

    left.insert(left.end(), middle.begin(), middle.end());
    left.insert(left.end(), right.begin(), right.end());
    
    return left;
}
```

У представленной выше реализации быстрой сортировки есть два серьёзных недостатка.

Во-первых, опасность переполнения стека всё ещё сохраняется. В худшем случае функция сортировки будет разбивать массив длины `n` на три подмассива с длинами `n-1`, `1` и `0`. При каждом рекурсивном вызове длина большего подмассива может получаться всего на единицу меньше, чем длина сортируемого массива. В таком случае, глубина рекурсии будет пропорциональна длине исходного массива.

Во-вторых, в худшем случае понадобится `O(n**2)` дополнительной памяти для хранения подмассивов.

Первый недостаток можно решить устранением одного из рекурсивных вызовов. Меньший из подлежащих сортировке подмассивов необходимо сортировать с помощью рекурсивного вызова, а больший подмассив следует сортировать в текущем вызове функции. Тогда максимальная глубина рекурсии в худшем случае будет пропорциональна `log(n)`, где `n` — длина исходного массива.

Второй недостаток решается сортировкой на месте. Нет никакой необходимости создавать дополнительные подмассивы. Достаточно перемещать элементы сортируемого массива на нужные позиции непосредственно в сортируемом массиве.

К тому же не помешало бы в качестве опорного элемента выбирать что-нибудь посложнее, например, медиану из первого, среднего и последнего элементов. Такая стратегия не исключит вероятность наступления худшего случая, но уменьшит.

[Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be5bf30834b312d5):

```
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

template <typename RandomIt, typename Compare>
void qsort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp)
{
    using std::swap;
    while (true)
    {
        auto dist = std::distance(first, last);
        if (dist <= 1)
            return;

        auto& first_val  = *first;
        auto& last_val   = *(last - 1);
        if (dist == 2)
        {
            if (comp(last_val, first_val))
                swap(last_val, first_val);
            return;
        }

        auto middle = first + dist / 2;
        auto& middle_val = *middle;
        if (comp(middle_val, first_val))
            swap(middle_val, first_val);
        if (comp(last_val, first_val))
            swap(last_val, first_val);
        if (comp(last_val, middle_val))
            swap(last_val, middle_val);
        if (dist == 3)
            return;

        swap(first_val, middle_val);
        auto inc_first = first;
        auto dec_last = last - 1;
        while (true)
        {
            do
                ++inc_first;
            while (comp(*inc_first, first_val));
            do
                --dec_last;
            while (comp(first_val, *dec_last));
            if (inc_first >= dec_last)
                break;
            swap(*inc_first, *dec_last);
        }

        if (inc_first - first > last - inc_first)
        {
            qsort(inc_first, last, comp);
            last = inc_first;
        }
        else
        {
            qsort(first, inc_first, comp);
            first = inc_first;
        }
    }
}

template <typename RandomIt>
void qsort(RandomIt first, RandomIt last)
{
    qsort(first, last, std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::value_type>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас идет переполнение стека из-за того что у вас рекурсия не останавливается,
В интернете полно готовых решений по быстрой сортировке, например вот
https://prog-cpp.ru/sort-fast/
можете посмотреть и сравнить что у вас не так

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 20
// Функция быстрой сортировки
void quickSort(int *numbers, int left, int right)
{
  int pivot; // разрешающий элемент
  int l_hold = left; //левая граница
  int r_hold = right; // правая граница
  pivot = numbers[left];
  while (left < right) // пока границы не сомкнутся
  {
    while ((numbers[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
      right--; // сдвигаем правую границу пока элемент [right] больше [pivot]
    if (left != right) // если границы не сомкнулись
    {
      numbers[left] = numbers[right]; // перемещаем элемент [right] на место разрешающего
      left++; // сдвигаем левую границу вправо
    }
    while ((numbers[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
      left++; // сдвигаем левую границу пока элемент [left] меньше [pivot]
    if (left != right) // если границы не сомкнулись
    {
      numbers[right] = numbers[left]; // перемещаем элемент [left] на место [right]
      right--; // сдвигаем правую границу вправо
    }
  }
  numbers[left] = pivot; // ставим разрешающий элемент на место
  pivot = left;
  left = l_hold;
  right = r_hold;
  if (left < pivot) // Рекурсивно вызываем сортировку для левой и правой части массива
    quickSort(numbers, left, pivot - 1);
  if (right > pivot)
    quickSort(numbers, pivot + 1, right);
}
int main()
{
  int a[SIZE];
  // Заполнение массива случайными числами
  for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    a[i] = rand() % 201 - 100;
  // Вывод элементов массива до сортировки
  for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    printf("%4d ", a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  quickSort(a, 0, SIZE-1); // вызов функции сортировки
            // Вывод элементов массива после сортировки
  for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    printf("%4d ", a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Приведите код по ссылке в самом ответе, чтобы при инвалидации ссылки он сохранил смысл

Comment: @dIm0n добавил код